# cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, forecasting, arima

I'm trying the code for ARIMA forecasting. Below are my code :

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
for i in range(n_test_obser):
  model = ARIMA(training_data, order=(0,1,1))
  model_fit = model.fit()
  output = model_fit.forecast()
  yhat =output
  model_predictions.append(yhat)
  actual_test_value = testing_data[i]
  training_data.append(actual_test_value)
  break
```

But, the results said that "cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid"

The whole line of error are down below:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-111-ee6cafdf936a> in <cell line: 4>()
      9   model_predictions.append(yhat)
     10   actual_test_value = testing_data[i]
---> 11   training_data.append(actual_test_value)

4 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
    456                     "only Series and DataFrame objs are valid"
    457                 )
--> 458                 raise TypeError(msg)
    459 
    460             ndims.add(obj.ndim)

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

What should I do to make the code works?

Comment: can you give the exact error traceback (which line, what function etc.) ?

Comment: the error line is in the function "training_data.append(actual_test_value)"

Comment: please provide the whole traceback (with all nested functions etc) as described in https://realpython.com/python-traceback/#what-is-a-python-traceback. With just the info you provided, we can only make assumptions about your error

Comment: I'm sorry, I just added it. Thank you

Comment: what datatype is your training_data? I suppose it is a pandas.DataFrame or pandas.Series. Both of those can only append arrays of a certain shape, which is why you are getting the error. If you would provide the datatype (and shape) of the training_data and the actual_test_value, I can help  you further.

Comment: Yes, it is pandas as datatype. But, I'm not sure about the shape of datatype

Comment: Dataframe append method is used to append rows to a dataframe i.e. you can only append a dataframe like object to a dataframe using the append() method.

What I see from your code is that you are appending an integer to a dataframe, which will not be allowed.

If you could specify what you want to achieve exactly, someone could help you.

Comment: what is `model_predictions.append(yhat)` doing?  Is `model_predictions` a list.  Lists can append anything.  `pandas` (and numpy) 'appends' are not list clones.